# How to create a Jumbotron in JHipster 6.10.3 using Bootstrap 4.5.0

Tags: bootstrap-4, jhipster, angular10

I'm trying to create a Jumbotron in JHipster(Angular 10) as seen on this westsite [enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/) but I does not work, and i have no specific error, could some body help me please?

Comment: Please edit your question to show some code you tried. When there's no error it usually means missing CSS styles or classes